# the mail function and the word "activate"

Tags: php, email

the mail function in php work only when i add the word "activate" in the message and if i remove this word the function does not work

```
        $to         ="$email";
        $from       ="mina nasser <mark@yahoo.com>";
        $subject    ="Login Password Generated";
        $message="<br />New Login  Password <br />
        activate Your New Password for our site is:<u>$temp_pass</u><br />";
        $headers     ="from:{$from}\r\n";
        $headers   .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers   .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

please some one help me

Answer (score 2):

```
 $message='<br />New Login  Password <br />
    activate Your New Password for our site is:<u>$temp_pass</u><br />';
```

It should be in Double quotes to parse `$temp_pass` as a variable

```
 $message="<br />New Login  Password <br />
    activate Your New Password for our site is:<u>{$temp_pass}</u><br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "does not work" is not an adequate description of your problem. What is the error message? In what way does it not work?
2. Check if `mail()` is returning true or false.
3. If true, check your mail logs.
4. If nothing in the mail logs check your spam folder.
5. If you're not using MIME/multipart messages then don't set a MIME header.
6. Set a date header.

   ```
   $headers .= 'Date: ' . date(DATE_RFC2822);
   ```

Comment: thanks  for replying                                                      actually the function return true but when I check my mail i don't receive any messages